# prestashop.How to add to the admin menu your item?

Tags: prestashop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYh3u.png)There is a shop at prestashop. I need to make a new section in the admin area, in which there will be a page with a form for adding data to the database. For this, I created the AdminNewDataController.php controller.

In this regard, tell me how to insert for this new item in the store admin menu?

Answer (score 0):

In function install :

```
$tabClass = 'AdminNewDataController';
        $tabName = 'Name of module';
        $idTabParent = 2;
        if (Db::getInstance()->getValue('SELECT Count(*) FROM ' . DB_PREFIX . 'tab WHERE class_name LIKE "' . pSQL($tabClass) . '"')) {
            return false;
        }

        $tab = new Tab();

        // $tab->name = $tabName;
        foreach (Language::getLanguages(false) as $lang) {
            $tab->name[(int) $lang['id_lang']] = $tabName;
        }

        $tab->class_name = $tabClass;
        $tab->module = $this->name;
        $tab->id_parent = $idTabParent;
        $tab->active = 1;
```